# Proxy config returns 404

Tags: angular

My backend can be reached by the URL `http://localhost:80/something`.

My package.json includes `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json"`.

**proxyconfig.json**

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

If I run `this.http.get<Itechnologies[]>('/api/something')`, I'll get

> GET http://localhost:4200/api/something 404 (Not Found)

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation will make a call to `http://localhost:80/api/something`.

So you'll need to use the `pathRewrite` option:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!